# Using Zend view helper from admin module with default module layout

Tags: zend-framework, layout, module, view-helpers

I have a view helper being called in my layout that works fine in the default module, but I get an exception when I am in another module.

I have already changed my app.ini to use the default layout across all modules by setting:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

And searching here and google provided me with another app.ini setting to add the view helper path for all modules:

```
resources.view.helperPath.Zend_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

However instead of fixing the problem, that additional setting causes the Zend Exception to become a WSOD.

Without that second app.ini setting, I see the layout and get this exception:

```
Plugin by name 'AutoScript' was not found in the registry; used paths: Admin_View_Helper_: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dad/application/modules/admin/views/helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:./views/helpers/
```

With the helperPath.Zend_View_Helper ini setting I get a WSOD with the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'AutoScript' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:./views/helpers/'
```

It appears the plugin loader is looking in public/views/helpers/ for the AutoScript.php file even though it should be using the APPLICATION_PATH value as a prefix.

My layout invocation looks like this

```
<?php $this->AutoScript(); ?>
```

My AutoScript.php file's class is defined in application/views/helpers/

```
class Zend_View_Helper_AutoScript extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
  public function AutoScript() {...}
}
```

My current fix is to copy the AutoScript.php file from application/views/helpers into modules/admin/views/helpers which fixes the issue, but duplicates a file. What am I missing? Do I have to add this view helper path programmatically by creating an _initView function in my bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would name your custom view helper with your own prefix, not the `Zend_` prefix. Beyond that, there are several choices for where to put and name your view helpers.

If this view-helper is really a single-application helper, then I find it natural for it to reside somewhere in the `application` folder. Within that possibility space, I would ask if the view-helper will be used in a *single* module or across *multiple* modules.

If the view-helper is intended for use in a *single* module, then I depend upon the build-in resource-autoloader mappings and place my view-helper class `Mymodule_View_Helper_Myhelper` in the file `application/modules/mymodule/views/helpers/Myhelper.php`.

If the view-helper is intended for use across *multiple* modules , I might pull it up a little higher than the `modules` folder, say `Application_View_Helper_Myhelper` (assuming an `appnamespace` of `Application`) stored in 
`application/views/helpers/Myhelper.php`. In this case, we need to tell the view that there are helpers with prefix `Application_View_Helper_` in that directory. This can be done at bootstrap:

```
protected function _initViewHelperPaths()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers', 'Application_View_Helper_');
}
```

Sometimes, you need a view-helper in one module that exists in another module and you cannot - in practical terms - move the original one around. In that case, one workaround is to define an empty shell of a view-helper in your consuming module extending your unmovable view-helper. In file `application/mymodule/views/helpers/MyHelper.php`:

```
class Mymodule_View_Helper_Myhelper extends Othermodule_View_Helper_Myhelper
{
}
```

This way, the code for the helper implementation is not duplicated. The module-specific resource-autoloader mappings will allow all those classes to be found when they invoked as view-helpers from a view-script.

Finally, if this view helper is to be used in *multiple projects*, then there is an argument for placing it outside of application scope, out in in the `library` folder. So perhaps a class `MyLibrary_View_Helper_Myhelper` stored in the file `library/MyLibrary/View/Helper/Myhelper.php`. As before, you would need to inform the view - probably at bootstrap or in a front-controller plugin - of the prefix/path mapping:

```
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATON_PATH . '/../library/MyLibrary/View/Helper', 'MyLibrary_View_Helper_');
```

Note that in all cases above, the invocation of the view-helper functionality itself - say, inside a view-script - is:

```
<?php echo $this->myhelper($params) ?>
```

Note, in particular, the casing difference between the classname and the invocation.

Comment: Thanks, I ran through these scenarios while researching the Zend docs for view helpers across modules. In my case, it was a cross module, application specific view helper I needed to work. I don't know why, but my problem went away without having to add the initViewHelperPaths function to my bootstrap. The difference in case between my classname and helper invocation was due to a suggestion that some (linux) servers don't like the case difference between the class name and helper call.

Comment: Yeah, in my experience, most Linux filesystems appear to be case-specific. Even in the absence of that, ZF itself has its own case conventions for the name of the view-helper class and the method name you use in the invocation. Anyway, glad it worked out for you. Cheers!